# How can I learn Yemenite ta'amei hamikrah?

Tags: torah-reading, trop-cantillation, yemenite-temani

I'm working with a student for his bar mitzvah whose family is Yemenite in origin, but has no living relatives who remember much of their tradition.  He is interested in learning to *leyn* with Yemenite *ta'amei hamikra*, which I think is wonderful, but raises the challenge of how to help him learn it.

Obviously, the best approach would be to find a Yemenite *ba'al koreh* willing and able to work with my student, but for various reasons I think it may be easier to learn the Yeminite system myself and then teach him.  (I'm also very interested!)

I'm considered an excellent ba'al kriyah in my community, with a thorough understanding of how the *t'amim* work (conjuctives, disjunctives of various levels, etc.), which I think gives me a good framework for this learning.

I've found a few recordings of Yemenite chanting online, and a few descriptions of how the trope system works, but I'm curious if anyone knows of great resources on this, or has ideas of how else I could be learning it.

Comment: where do you live? i learned it myself by following along in the beith ha kannasath. if you live in bk i can get you some adresses to places where you can go to learn.

Comment: @MoriDoweedh The OP's [linked account](http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/users/63/benj) on [salesforce.se] says "St. Paul, MN".

Comment: @DoubleAA :/ there is a miqra book at nosahteiman.com i think. i am not sure how good it is if a person doesnt know how it sounds what good does it do.

Comment: Yup, I'm in St. Paul, MN -- not a big temani community here...

Comment: @MoriDoweedhYaa3gob can you link to the book?  I just tried that website and it seems to be down.

Comment: http://www.nosachteiman.co.il/?CategoryID=498 in the beith ha kannasath we have ספר לימוד לתינוקות של בית רבן במסורת יהודי תימן יע"א from that site. It is ok, some letters there are mislabeled as beith instead if bei and so on. But it's good for starters.

Comment: Thanks, @MoriDoweedhYaa3gob.  Before ordering this, I want to clarify that I'm not looking to teach temani pronunciation of the Hebrew, but the temani system of t'amim and their melodies.  Not much available online besides the cover of that book, and it's hard to tell whether it's about language or keriyah.

Comment: It's both. Teimonim teach how to pronounce while teaching how to lein. From what I remember, the trop was in the beginning of the book. I Am not 100% sure, so don't buy it atm. You can buy a cd or wat h YouTube videos of teimonim leining, and get a teimonim 7ummash to follow along.

Comment: Related: http://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/66371 (cc @MoriDoweedhYaa3qob )

Comment: http://www.moryapp.co.il/ is helpful for the future.

Comment: https://anchor.fm/avishayy/episodes/--Bamidbar-First-Oncelus--Shabbat-e1g37h2

Answer (score 2):

I'm Netanel, from Israel.
My father-in-law is Baal-Kore and he is also Mori in his Yemenite community. He is very professional and teaching kids for Bar-Mitzva as a way of life.
If it is still relevant, you are most welcome to contact me and we will arrange it. We will find the way to do it.

Comment: Thanks for the note!  No longer relevant, but I'll keep in mind.

Answer (score 2):

I found this website which contains full recordings of the Temani traditional reading (including full Hebrew pronunciation and ta'am, and recordings of the Haftarah verse-for-verse including Targum). It's all-Hebrew, but it's not hard to navigate.

http://www.moryapp.co.il/

Comment: Do they have a recording of just the te'amim list/Zarqa Table?

Comment: Website is down.

Answer (score 0):

Just for the record, Yemenite ta'amim are more flexible than Ashkenazi & Mizrachi ta'amim. The are more related to length held as opposed to moving. There is great variation among Yemenite ta'amim with not only regional differences, but even family differences. If you want to help that boy out, you should try & find out what village & family his father was from & see if you can track down a male relative who still has the tradition.

Comment: Welcome to Mi Yodeya Ra'anan! Thank you very much for the answer! Hopefully you will choose to continue enriching the site with your knowledge of Yemenite practice, and with anything else.