# Is there a Yemenite Taamei Hamikra teacher in Brooklyn?

Tags: torah-reading, chutz-laaretz, adult-learning, yemenite-temani, shnayim-mikra

I was saying shnayim mikra today and bemoaned the fact I don't know how to read it with the trope in the Yemenite tradition. I was wondering if anyone knew where I can learn it from someone locally near me who can teach me. I've found some online resources, but I am more interested in someone who can teach me personally. Is there someone or an institution that is known in or near Brooklyn that can help me?

I've done some research myself but my leads came up cold.

I have a tikun of my own, if that helps.

Comment: That link certainly points me in the right direction but I was asking more if there was someone I could learn from locally. In fact it's mentioned in that thread but I can't message @MoriDoweedhYaa3qob

Comment: If I were you, I would upvote the original question. I might have found a cd set that could help teach you.

Comment: It seems to me this question is now sufficiently distinguished from [the other](/q/34683) in that the other asks for resources and by implication *not* a teacher, since the asker already mentions a teacher, whereas this asks for teachers specifically. I'm reopening; cc @DoubleAA

Comment: I an also a Ba'al Kri'ah and I live near Brooklyn. I will try to follow this question. But, in case I forgot, if you get an answer or locate someone, and don't mind my sharing a lesson with you, please ping me.

Comment: @EliyahuHaTalmid theres 5 teimoni battei kannasath in brooklyn. http://jewishyemenites.com/JY_synog.html i got to masoroth ovoth on dahill. the reading there is not so good. the best reading is on ave j and e 2nd. hayyim ban sur welcomes people to come and learn. get in contact with him and you can learn a thing or two there. never been to the one on ave o e 9th but i heard good things bout it in regards to the kashruth of the seifar toro. and they read good as well i heard but not as good as on ave j.

Comment: @MoriDoweedhYaa3qob masoroth ovoth is close to kings highway? I'd love to come for shaharith

Comment: @EliyahuHaTalmid no masoroth ovoth is on dahill near toro wa doath. the one close to kings highway is on ave o and east 9